# loop until meet a class then do something

Tags: javascript, html, zepto

http://jsfiddle.net/ytytb5hu/

How can I make all the the `p` up to `class="here"` the color of red using a loop?

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p class="here">4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

```js
.here {
    border:1px solid;
}
p {
    color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why use a loop? `$('.here').css('color', 'red');`

Comment: If you know the index, use $('p').eq(3).css(

Comment: I believe OP wants _all elements up to_ the matching class to get red. Not only the matching class.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi my data is dynamic, can't do it that way.

Comment: Are these elements all in a container?

Comment: Is there any consistency between the indexes of the elements you want to stop styling at? e.g., is it always the 4th one or 2nd last one? Is the class in your question for illustrative purposes only or will you be giving the last element to be styled a class in your live code too?

Comment: Also, can you update your question with a use case? As it stands, this can be achieved with some basic CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? :

```
$('p').prevUntil('.here').css('color', 'red');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vpLdn0cp/)**

If you only want to change a specific element you can add a second paramenter:

```
$('p').prevUntil('.here', 'p').css('color', 'red');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vpLdn0cp/2/)**

The function `prevUntil()` will select all previous siblings of the element exluding the element wich matches the selector.

**Reference**

[.prevUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

Comment: sad zepto doesn't have this function.

Comment: @AaronMusktin This would be a good information in your question

Answer (score 3):

Try excluding selectors at `:not()` , return filtered collection

```js
$("p:not(.here, .here ~ p)").css("color", "red");
```

```css
.here {
    border:1px solid;
}
p {
    color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p class="here">4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way but this would work:

```js
$('p:eq(0)').addClass('red').nextUntil('.here').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red{
    
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p class="here">4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

Comment: I have to use loop before I'm using zepto

Comment: @AaronMusktin ok, ill look at that, but you should probably add that to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use, less than operator `lt(index)` if you know the index

```
$('p:lt(4)').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `.here` index and use `lt`:

```
$('p:lt(' + $('p.here').index() + ')').css('color', 'red');
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/ytytb5hu/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[3].setAttribute('class','here');
```

or

```
document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("p")[3].setAttribute('class','here');
```

css:

```
.here{
    color:red;
}
```